# Turn Off Push Notification function By Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification

I want to make the function that turn off push notification off the app 
(at the setting page)
by Uiswitch

How can i do it

Thanks!

Edited
Add example photo

[image]

Comment: Local Notification or APNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the application, it is near to impossible, but you can set your change your Service which send Push notification.

If you are using `APNS`, than you must send Device token to your server, for send push notification.

You can make call to server for disable it with the device token you passed. You can make call on switch value change.

Comment: @VarisDarasirikul, Close the question if you get your solution.

Comment: But how to disable device token.

Comment: @PintuRajput Disabling token is not possible, token will be fetched from `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, so what you can do is passing null value to your server when you want to disable it.

Comment: @ViralSavaj Enabling and disabling Notification from my App itself.

Answer (score -1):

Use this ...

The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.

```
if types == UIRemoteNotificationType.None {}

UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil))
```

[Note for PushNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)...